# how can I check "is_file" in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I use "tinyMCE" as dynamic on one page.

So I have to use "setContent" to change content in "tinyMCE".

However, I don't know how to check is_file(in PHP  checking file existing or not) in ajax or before go ajax.

Please let me know~

```
        $(".editor-button").bind("click", function(){
            var title, file;
            title = $(this).data("title");                  
            $(".ui-dialog-title").text(title);
            switch (match_arr[title]) {
                case 1:
                    file = "../../front/footer/about_us.html";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    file = "../../front/footer/return_policy.html";
                    break;
                default:
            }

            $.ajax({
                url : file,
                dataType: "html",
                success : function (html){
                    html != "" ? tinyMCE.get('text-box').setContent(html) : tinyMCE.get('text-box').setContent('');
                }
            });

            $("#text-editor-dialog").dialog("open");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to like a following ajax code and it works.

```
            $.ajax({
                url : file,
                dataType: "html",
                success : function (html){
                    tinyMCE.get('text-box').setContent(html);
                },
                error : function (){
                    tinyMCE.get('text-box').setContent('');
                }
            });
```